# AddThis FaceBook sharing without webpage scraping

Tags: javascript, facebook, backbone.js

I have a web application that is built on Backbone JS framework, that is most URLs have a hashtag section in them. For example: www.abcd.com/xyz.shtml#/route1
the 'route1' is the name of a defined execution route which causes contents including the meta-tags of the page to be populated dynamically on-load by making a number of AJAX calls to the server. I'm not able to integrate AddThis Facebook-share because when FB scrapes the URL it doesn't execute the JS section defined by the 'route1' and thus none of the meta-tags are populated!

Can anyone suggest me a way to bypass this scraping process of FB and/or lets me supply the relevant parameters to FB and FB posts it directly without messing with the URL?

Many Thanks.

Comment: That is how sharing content on Facebook works – their crawler requests your content from the server, and expects the meta information to be contained within the response it is getting. And no, you can not “pass” these values any other way. So see to it, that you a) have individual URLs for each individual piece of content you want to share (a different hash part does _not_ make them different URLs), and b) that your server outputs the correct meta information directly when those URLs are requested.

Comment: Thanks CBroe! Can you suggest any other plugin like Addthis that can be used in this scenario?!